# Heroku domain connection failing

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I signed up with Heroku hobby plan ($7 / month), and that part works fine, but the problem is, I specified the domain in Heroku like this: `www.marcosbackyardswimming.ca`, and in go daddy, I did `CNAME, host: www, pointsto: Heroku.dns`

the problem with this is, the only way it actually goes to the site is when I go to `www.marcosbackyardswimming.ca`, and if I just type in `marcosbackyardswimming.ca`, it doesn't go there. how do I redirect or specify somewhere to go to `www.marcosbackyardswimming.com` even if I just type in `marcosbackyardswimming.com`?

Comment: Who is providing your DNS servers? At those servers (web interface) create an A record for `marcosbackyardswimming.ca` with the IP address of your webserver. Create a CNAME for` www` with the value `marcosbackyardswimming.ca`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annoying thing is that Go Daddy and Heroku don't play nicely. Here are a few pointers.

1. Make sure SSL is set on Heroku.
2. Remove the superfluous Go Daddy A records
3. Set up forwarding on Go Daddy with https:// protocol to www

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that using this: https://imranhsayed.medium.com/adding-your-custom-domain-to-heroku-app-cdd68d2db67f